# Rails/Nginx: Routes work on dev not on prod

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, http-status-code-404, passenger

My application works perfectly in my development environment, but routes don't work in my production server running nginx and Passenger, where I get:

```
404 Not Found
```

However, the index page does work as well as CSS and JavaScript.

I thought it was related to locale or i18n issues, but by changing routes.rb to remove `:locale` I got the same output.

Routes:

```
$ rake routes
                   Prefix Verb URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
                          GET  /:locale(.:format)                                                                       welcome#index
                 services GET  /:locale/services(.:format)                                                              welcome#services
                 projects GET  /:locale/projects(.:format)                                                              welcome#projects
                  contact GET  /:locale/contact(.:format)                                                               welcome#contact
                          GET  /:locale(.:format)                                                                       welcome#index
                     root GET  /                                                                                        welcome#index
       rails_service_blob GET  /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id/*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET  /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format) active_storage/representations#show
       rails_disk_service GET  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
update_rails_disk_service PUT  /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                      active_storage/disk#update
     rails_direct_uploads POST /rails/active_storage/direct_uploads(.:format)                                           active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Nginx/site-enable:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/test.com/public;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name test.com www.test.com;

    # Turn on Passenger
    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/ubuntu/.rbenv/versions/2.5.1/bin/ruby;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
```

I'm using:
 - Ruby 2.5.1
 - gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'

`production.log` shows the rendering of the Welcome page but not `/en/services` for example when trying to go there:

```
I, [2020-02-23T17:08:28.146331 #19532]  INFO -- : [4cd74925-0637-4b92-92aa-12f693691ecb] Processing by WelcomeController#index as HTML
I, [2020-02-23T17:08:28.146998 #19532]  INFO -- : [4cd74925-0637-4b92-92aa-12f693691ecb]   Rendering welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application
I, [2020-02-23T17:08:28.147227 #19532]  INFO -- : [4cd74925-0637-4b92-92aa-12f693691ecb]   Rendered welcome/index.html.erb within layouts/application (0.1ms)
I, [2020-02-23T17:08:28.148286 #19532]  INFO -- : [4cd74925-0637-4b92-92aa-12f693691ecb] Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.4ms)
```

nginx/error.log:

```
[ N 2020-02-23 17:13:07.1716 25594/T1 age/Wat/WatchdogMain.cpp:1373 ]: Starting Passenger watchdog...
[ N 2020-02-23 17:13:07.1994 25602/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1340 ]: Starting Passenger core...
[ N 2020-02-23 17:13:07.1995 25602/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:256 ]: Passenger core running in multi-application mode.
[ N 2020-02-23 17:13:07.2058 25602/T1 age/Cor/CoreMain.cpp:1015 ]: Passenger core online, PID 25602
```

nginx/access.log:

```
[23/Feb/2020:17:14:23 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "http://www.XXX.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36"
[23/Feb/2020:17:14:28 +0000] "GET /en/services HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "http://www.XXX.fr/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.106 Safari/537.36"
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please don't add a summary like "fixed" to your question. It confuses people. Questions are just that, the question, and answers are attempts to solve the question. If you solved the problem on your own then it's acceptable and appropriate to create an answer that shows the solution, then, when Stack Overflow allows, select your answer as the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by looking into log file of your application, 404 response could be caused by many elements of your stack. 
When you open your application root page you should see a request logged to `log/production.log` file (assuming this is in production environment). If you don't see it, look up the stack at nginx error log (normally Passenger is using this one for stderr).

Comment: I edited my post with production.log ; can see the log about rendering welcome page (index) but not any other pages...

Comment: Fixed; see initial post!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by commenting the "location" part of the nginx conf:

```
#       location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
#               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
#       }
```

Comment: Glad to hear you solved your problem.

My $0.02: are you sure that your `log/production.log` is showing correct information? I don't see a route that will answer `/welcome/index` request in the `rake routes` results. There is a module in RoR that answers this, this is the **You are riding ruby on rails** landing page in every new rails application.
I am not sure about nginx.conf file, I just had a quick look at https://www.phusionpassenger.com/docs/tutorials/deploy_to_production/deploying_your_app/oss/ownserver/ruby/nginx/#rails_edit-nginx-configuration-file and they don't use this option.